Use customized properties of ObjectMapper in a JsonSerializer
Is it possible to somehow customize an ObjectMapper instance so that I can access this customization in a JsonSerializer?
Let's assume that I can create the ObjectMapper myself but I don't have access over the POJOs that are serialized. Further assume that the JsonSerializer is shared with a lot of projects.
I'd like to have a feature, just like one of the built-in MapperFeatures, that toggles something. In my JsonSerializer I want to check whether the feature is enabled and serialize one way or the other.
Here is the signature of serialize:
public void serialize(ZonedDateTime date, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {


What part of the ObjectMapper do you need? Because a lot of its configuration is available through the JsonGenerator or SerializerProvider. Both provide access to some of the features.

The code uses the object mapper to serialize objects. I provide the object mapper to that code (I can't change this). The serializer is registered in that instance. The serialize comes from a shared project (I can change the code of it). So what I'm looking for is some method/attribute/feature that I can set on the ObjectMapper and access it through one of the parameters available in the serialize method of the serializer.

The SerialzierProvider should be able to give you the serializer you need. That's its main purpose.

We can implement custom serializable in such a way below
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

    public class CustomObjectMapper {
    
        public static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
            // Create a module for custom serializers
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    
            // Add custom serializer to the module
            module.addSerializer(MyCustomClass.class, new MyCustomSerializer());
    
            // Register the module with the ObjectMapper
            mapper.registerModule(module);
    
            // Additional configuration (if needed)
            // mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
            // mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    
            return mapper;
        }
    }


That is exactly what I did to register my custom serializer. But it doesn't answer my question. How can the code, that calls createObjectMapper modify the ObjectMapper in a way that the serializer knows about it.

yes we can Serialize and Deserialize java object and json String with
Jackson Library (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)
public class SerializeExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Address address = new Address("123 ", "Spring", "12345");
        Person person = new Person("Mr A", 30, address);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public class DeserializeExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Mr A\",\"age\":30,\"address\":{\"street\":\"123\",\"city\":\"Spring\",\"zipCode\":\"12345\"}}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Person.class);

        System.out.println("Name: " + person.getName());
        System.out.println("Age: " + person.getAge());
        System.out.println("Address: " + person.getAddress().getStreet() + ", " + person.getAddress().getCity() + ", " + person.getAddress().getZipCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


Please make sure you understand the question before you post.
